# Finitely generated quotient field

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

If $K$, the quotient field of a commutative integral domain $R$, is finitely generated as an $R$-module, is $R$ necessarily a field?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that the fractions $a_1/b_1,a_2/b_2,\ldots, a_t/b_t$ generate $K$ as an $R$-module.
Let $s\in R$ be an arbitrary non-zero element. As the product $r=sb_1b_2\cdots b_t$ is non-zero, the fraction $1/r$ exists in $K.$ Therefore there exist elements $r_i\in R$, $1\le i\le t$, such that
$$
\frac1r=\sum_{i=1}^tr_i\cdot\frac{a_i}{b_i}.
$$
Using this it should be easy to see that $1/s\in R$.

Comment: Another question: when **P** is a prime ideal of **R**, could one say that **R_P/PR_P**  is the quotient field of **R/P**?

Comment: @karparvar, if you have another question, ask it as such, citing this one if relevant

Answer (score 2):

Since   $K$ is a field and is integral ($\Leftarrow$ module finite) over $R$ ,  $R$ is a field too : Proposition 5.7 [here](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Introduction_To_Commutative_Algebra.html?id=HOASFid4x18C&redir_esc=y) .

Comment: Jyrki's answer is more didactic because self-contained, but I could never  resist the temptation of a one-liner :-)